# to enter a time to sqlite database using java which doesnot exist in the database before

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using java and sqlite as back end my requirement is I have to enter a time to the database,i have 2 fields starttime and endtime in database and while registering i have to check whether that time slot is already used by another user ?

Comment: You can insert timestamp in record

Comment: You could put a constraint on the two times to be unique...

Answer (score 0):

I guess for that first you have to calculate EndTime-StartTime=RequiredSlot
Then you have to run query on database to check if RequiredSlot is assign to anyone else.
Considering Same Date..